# How to add *.txt file package(together with other *.class files) in jar?

Tags: gradle

I need to include *.txt file in package with *.class files after build task.

I know how to add resource in jar. But how to add text file together with *.class files in package?

Comment: You put them in src/main/resources, under the package you want.

Comment: @JBNizet How must I put? I can't create required package in resources folder.

Comment: Yes, you can. Why couldn't you?

Comment: @JBNizet I use Intellij IDEA. If I invoke context menu on resources folder I don't see new package button.

Comment: Then choose "new Directory", and type the directory path. You realize that in the end, creating a package simply creates directories on the file system, right?